# Is there a possibility to get table contain in the controller?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm building an electronic shop, for making an order, I gather the selected products in a table.
Now I want to save my order and the detail order.
I want know if it's possible how to get that data for that I could save it.

Comment: You have to specify the problem. Do you have any code reproduction? Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What are you looking for? I doubt a yes or no answer will help you. Do you understand why we're going to find it hard to help you at the moment?